# Missing Wiimote and Nunchuk axis/button inputs on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: bluetooth, gamepad, wii

I'm trying to use my Wii Remote (the RVL-CNT-01 model) and Nunchuk as a game controller on Ubuntu 21.10. However, it appears that only the buttons on the Wiimote are recognized out-of-the-box. How would I configure Ubuntu to pick up the Wiimote motion axis and Nunchuk inputs?

Similar topics on Ask Ubuntu advise using `jstest` to make sure that the controller works properly. When doing so, I get the following message:

```
Driver version is 2.1.0.
Joystick (Nintendo Wii Remote) has 0 axes ()
and 7 buttons (BtnA, BtnB, BtnMode, (null), (null), Btn1, Btn2).
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Buttons:  0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
```

All seven buttons listed do work when I test them.
Also, it seems like Ubuntu has mapped the D-pad to the arrow keys and blocked off access to them.

`xwiishow` was able to detect the D-pad and the motion input on the Wii Remote, and it detected the presence of the Nunchuk but didn't show any information about it.

Please let me know if I need to provide any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XWiimote):

> **The input mapping is very weird**
> The default mapping maps the Wii Remote keys to the the key-constants which resemble the Wii Remote's buttons best. This mapping is quite useless by default. To get better mappings, use the xwiimote userspace tools. Installing [xwiimote-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xwiimote-git/) will add an [Xorg configuration file](https://github.com/dvdhrm/xwiimote/blob/master/res/50-xorg-fix-xwiimote.conf) that disables the default mapping.

[hid-wiimote](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/hid/hid-wiimote-modules.c) maps the D-pad to `KEY_LEFT`, `KEY_RIGHT`, `KEY_UP`, `KEY_DOWN` which is unusual. Most gamepads map the D-pad to `ABS_HAT0X`, `ABS_HAT0Y` but it looks like hid-wiimote uses hat switches for IR data. [joydev](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/input/joydev.c) only looks at keys above `BTN_MISC` when mapping buttons which explains why the D-pad buttons aren't there. I'd guess the other two are `KEY_NEXT` (minus) and `KEY_PREVIOUS` (previous). See the full list of input event codes [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h).